# How to invoke a class in another package?

Tags: java, class, import

I'm on a starter project and I split it in two packages in Eclipse and one of them has the main method and another .java class and the other one has anothers .java class with secondary methods.
I want  to know how do I invoke a method present in the secondary package to use it in the .java class that doesn't have the main method in the primary. How do I import it and how do I access a method from that class? I'm new to java and need this to a project.

Comment: Maybe you just specify the package name?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly (maybe it is better if you paste some sample code) write your code in the main method, calling what you need.
Then write the imports that you need on the top or with CTRL+MAIUSC+O in Eclipse you will import the needed packages.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `import` in the beginning of the class, but Eclipse makes it automatically for you if you use its shortcut to auto-import (should be `Ctrl + Shift + O`).

Something like this:

Class `User`

```
package model;

public class User {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getAge() { return this.name; }
    public void setAge(Integer age) { this.age = age; }

    @Override
    public void toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.name + "; Age: " + this.age;
    }
}
```

Class `UserAttributes` (where you need to import the other class)

```
package logic;

import model.User; //this is the line you must include (or hit Ctrl+Shift+O in Eclipse)

public class UserAttributes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User john = new User("john", 30);

        System.out.println(john);
    }
}
```

Eclipse can be a nice tool to develop and makes your life much easier if you use its features. Some of them have direct access via shortcuts. Here's a [list of some very useful](https://dzone.com/articles/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key) (in my opinion).

Hope it's somehow helpful.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, here's my code

```
package ex_19;
import ex_16_17.Date;
import ex_18.HeartRates;

public class HealthProfile {
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private String sexo;
    private Date dataNascimento;
    private float altura;
    private float peso;

.......

    HeartRates hr = new HeartRates(this.getNome(), this.getSobrenome(), this.dataNascimento.getDia(), this.dataNascimento.getMes(), this.dataNascimento.getAno());

    public int calcIdade(){
        return hr.calculaIdade();
    }

    public int freqMaxima(){
        return hr.feqMax();
    }

    public String freqAlvo(){
        return hr.feqAlvo();
    }
```

I wanna know how to use a code like this, working on my main, when I call the calcIdade(), what is the syntaxe?